# Azure ESB scheduled message resulting general error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure, azureservicebus

I am using @azure/service-bus (7.0.0) npm client to push scheduled message but its not getting pushed
all are failing with
error:{"name":"ServiceBusError","retryable":false,"code":"GeneralError"}}"

```
const sbClient = this.getInstance();
const sender = sbClient.createSender(queueOrTopic);
await sender.scheduleMessages(message, scheduleTimeUtc);
```

Above is the code snippet of how I am triggering.

Comment: Does it repro with this code ? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/javascript/scheduledMessages.js

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [azure-sdk-for-js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues)

Comment: @Jdresc Yes its reproducible in only production but when I am doing in staging or local its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below block of code to send timer based message. This will be added to the queue of messages and will be sent at the particular timeframe which is set.

```
public static async sendScheduleMessage(
    content: Message): Promise<string> {

const serviceConnection =
        AzureServiceBus.createConnection();

const client = serviceConnection.createQueueClient(
        "" + process.env.AZURE_SERVICEBUS_QUEUE);

const sender = client.createSender();
let response = "";

try {
    const scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc
        = moment().utc().add(1, "m").toDate();
    
    const sequenceId = await sender.scheduleMessage(
        scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc,
        {body: JSON.stringify(content),
        label: "MyTopic"});
    
    response = sequenceId.toString();
    await client.close();
} catch (error) {
    
} finally {
    await serviceConnection.close();
}

return resp;
}
```

basically in some cases there will be an issue with the sequenceid as it needs to be encoded, because the correct sequenceid is not passed to get the information of that message.
For this Azure has fixed it with the below solution:

```
import { DefaultDataTransformer }
            from "@azure/amqp-common";
...
...

const dt = new DefaultDataTransformer();

const sequenceId = await sender.scheduleMessage(
        scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc,
        {body: dt.encode(JSON.stringify(content)),
        label: "MyTopic"});

response = sequenceId.toString();
```

With all the above code, this can be achieved.